# SQL Trigger to record UPDATE into Audit Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with columns `businessname`, `sortcode` and `accountnumber` all populated, `name`, `nationality` and `DOB` all currently unpopulated. I need to create a trigger to shoot every update to an audit table when any of the null fields are updated so if I change just the name I'll get a timestamp, userid, the field changed, the old value and the new value.. If I changed all 3 null fields I'd like to send 3 rows to the audit table.

Can someone give me a pointer on the logic of this please?

In a very rudimentary format for testing I've got

```
CREATE TRIGGER RM_UPDATE_TRIGGER ON RM_BASE
ON UPDATE 
AS 
    INSERT INTO RM_AUDITLOG
       SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, SRT_CD
       FROM RM_BASE
```

but this is sending all the current rows across after an UPDATE to any of them, I only want the row that has been affected. I'm not sure if I should be building more tables to join together to get the final answer or using the INSERT/DELETE tables.. I've seen an audit table in this format in previous roles so I know it works but can't figure it out!

Thanks

Comment: Sorry - SQL server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use the `INSERTED` and/or `DELETED` pseudo-tables as those contain only the rows that have been modified. As in:

```
CREATE TRIGGER RM_UPDATE_TRIGGER ON RM_BASE
ON UPDATE 
AS 
    INSERT INTO RM_AUDITLOG
       SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, SRT_CD
       FROM INSERTED
```

The `INSERTED` table has the "new" or "current" version of each row while the `DELETED` table has the "old" version that has been replaced via the `UPDATE` operation. This is the case for all versions of SQL Server, at least going back as far as SQL Server 2000.

In order to track the change itself (both "old" and "new" values), then you need to JOIN those two pseudo-tables, as in:

```
  INSERT INTO RM_AUDITLOG
     SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ins.SRT_CD AS [SRT_CD_new], del.SRT_CD AS [SRT_CD_old]
     FROM INSERTED ins
     INNER JOIN DELETED del
             ON del.PKfield = ins.PKfield
```

This is the basic operation for capturing changes (unless, of course, you use [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx)) in a DML trigger.

If you want to [unpivot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) this data such that each set of "old" and "new" columns becomes a row, that should be easily adaptable from the above. In that case, you could also add `WHERE ISNULL(ins.column, '~~~~') <> ISNULL(del.column, '~~~~') COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN` to avoid capturing fields that have not changed. The `COLLATE` ensures case-sensitive / accent-sensitive / etc comparisons.

Of course, unpivoting makes it really hard to reconstruct the entire row as you are then required to keep the full history forever. You would need to start with the base values for all fields and apply the changes incrementally. The typical audit scenario is to just to capture the row that has fields for both old and new for each source field (like I have already shown). If your audit table looks more like:

`PKfield, DateModified, businessname_old, businessname_new, sortcode_old, sortcode_new`

then you can write a query to identify which fields actually changed by comparing each set (given that more than 1 field can change in the same `UPDATE` operation), something like:

```
SELECT PKfield,
       DateModified,
       CASE
         WHEN ISNULL(businessname_old, '~~~~') <> ISNULL(businessname_new, '~~~~')
              COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN THEN 'BusinessName ' ELSE ''
       END + 
       CASE
         WHEN ISNULL(sortcode_old, '~~~~') <> ISNULL(sortcode_new, '~~~~')
              COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN THEN 'SortCode ' ELSE ''
       END AS [FieldsChanged]
FROM  AuditTable
ORDER BY DateModified DESC;
```

BUT, if you *really* want to unpivot the data to have one row per actual changed field, then the following structure should work:

```
;WITH ins AS
(
   SELECT PKfield, FieldName, Value
   FROM   (
            SELECT PKfield, businessname, sortcode, accountnumber, name,
                   nationality, DOB
            FROM INSERTED
          ) cols
   UNPIVOT (Value FOR FieldName IN
               (businessname, sortcode, accountnumber, name, nationality, DOB)
           ) colvals
), del AS
(
   SELECT PKfield, FieldName, Value
   FROM   (
            SELECT PKfield, businessname, sortcode, accountnumber, name,
                   nationality, DOB
            FROM DELETED
          ) cols
   UNPIVOT (Value FOR FieldName IN
               (businessname, sortcode, accountnumber, name, nationality, DOB)
           ) colvals
)
INSERT INTO AuditTable (PKfield, DateModified, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue)
   SELECT ins.PKfield, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ins.FieldName, del.Value, ins.Value
   FROM   ins
   INNER JOIN del
           ON del.PKfield = ins.PKfield
          AND del.FieldName = ins.FieldName
   WHERE  ISNULL(del.Value, '~~~~') <>
             ISNULL(ins.Value, '~~~~') COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;
```

You *might* need to add a `CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), field)` to the `WHERE` condition if `DOB` is a `DATE` or `DATETIME` field, or if `SRT_CD` is an INT or other type of number field:

```
   WHERE  ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), del.Value), '~~~~') <>
             ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), ins.Value), '~~~~')
             COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;
```

Comment: Ah Awesome, thanks - I've never used the pseudo tables. How would I grab the Fieldname that has been updated from either inserted or deleted?

Comment: @user3294008 , first, I just re-read the question and it sounds like you only want to capture the fields when they go from `NULL` to having a value, but not when a non-NULL value changes to another non-NULL value. Is that correct or just mis-worded in the question?

Comment: No - I want to capture all changes from now on whether null or populated, it's just that they are all currently null

Comment: @user3294008 , that makes more sense and is what I had assumed to begin with. The only part that is not exactly what you are wanting is that the pseudo-tables need to be `UNPIVOT`ed first. I can update my answer to be the basic structure, but you will have to finish it from there.

Comment: That's fine - I understand all of the unpivot and that's not a requirement for my solution to be honest, but I do really want to bring in the column name that has been updated - Is there a quick easy way to do this?

Comment: @user3294008 , are you sure you want to unpivot this data such that each field is a row? That makes it really hard to reconstruct the entire row as you are then required to keep the full history forever. You would need to start with the base values for all fields and apply the changes incrementally. The typical audit scenario is to just to capture the row that has fields for both old and new for each source field (like I have already shown).

Comment: @user3294008: in order to get the column name you would need to manually test each field across `INSERTED` and `DELETED` as SQL Server does not capture the fact that the value itself has or has not changed, only that the field was present in the `UPDATE` DML query. So `UPDATE table SET field1 = new_value, field3 = new_value` will indicate that both `field1` and `field3` have been "updated", but no indication if there was an actual change.

Comment: I think I understand - but what if using your trigger someone updates the ACC_NO instead of SRT_CD or updates all of the fields? Ideally I want the audit table to be USER, TIMESTAMP, CHANGEDFIELD, OLD_VALUE, NEW_VALUE so yeah each column has it's own row in the audittable

Comment: @user3294008, if someone updates 3 of the fields or all of the fields, you want to capture all of that, don't you?

Comment: @user3294008 : I just updated the answer again to show the unpivoted syntax that _should_ work, but I haven't tested it. If you want `USER`, then I assume that each person logs into SQL Server with a different Login, as opposed to everyone connecting via the same Login as in the case of a web-app. If you need an application Login (i.e. not Windows or SQL Server based) then you need to pass that in separately to the trigger via CONTEXT_INFO.

Comment: @user3294008 : np. Please see my most recent edit (bottom of the answer) regarding the possible need to add in a `CONVERT`.